# Spacemacs configuration in ORG mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know it's possible to make our `.spacemacs` configuration in `ORG mode` to be more readable, but i found nothing about it ...

Comment: This is the type of question where several people will give an opinion with sample configurations if the question were to appear on https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/ -- however, this type of a question is not well-received in this particular forum because it is not technically a classic programming question with sample code that almost works (but needs a little TLC) and a statement regarding the desired behavior and why the current behavior falls short of expectations.  The spacemacs gurus read the other forum.  Thus, consider deleting this question and posting it on a more suitable forum.

Comment: i already ask on gitter spacemacs, but i didn't get answered, so i thought maybe in this community i'll get one !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've spent some time looking for exactly same thing (but for pure Emacs though), I put here a couple of examples so that people could easily find it on SO:

- [Emacs configurations written in Org mode](https://github.com/larstvei/dot-emacs)
- [Emacs Configuration in Org-Mode](https://github.com/seth/my-emacs-dot-d)
- And the last but the best [answer on Emacs.StackExchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/can-i-use-org-mode-to-structure-my-emacs-or-other-el-configuration-file)

Comment: i already did mine, thanks for the answer !
If you want to look mine : https://github.com/ale-batt/spacemacs_conf